# Swift & Stripe fetch payment method from customer

Tags: swift, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use the customers saved payment method in stripe to make payments but I'm running into two issues.

1). I can't decode the JSON response that my server-side call sends to the app and get the `Payment Method Id`. I'm getting the full JSON response but when I attempt to print out the `ID` it returns nil.

2). If the users has multiple payment methods saved how will I know which they intend to use when decoding the JSON response to get the `Payment Method Id`?

The intended result would be for the user to be able to use the saved payment methods that they previously saved using the `STPPaymentOptionsViewController` to make payments but the two issues above persist.

**Server Side:**

```
exports.listUserSavedCards = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

var customerId = req.body.customer_id

const paymentMethods = await stripe.paymentMethods.list({
  customer: customerId,
  type: 'card',
}).then(function(paymentMethods) {
  // asynchronously called
  return res.send(paymentMethods);
});
})
```

**App Side:**

```
func listUserSavedCards(customerId: String) {

    let URLString = "https://us-central1-example.cloudfunctions.net/" + "listUserSavedCards" as String

    var requestData : [String : String]? = [String : String]()
    requestData?.updateValue(customerId, forKey: "customer_id");

    submitDataToURL(URLString, withMethod: "POST", requestData: requestData!) { (jsonResponse, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print(err)
            return
        }
        else {

            let response = jsonResponse["id"]


        }
    }
}
```

**JSON Response:**

```
["url": /v1/payment_methods, "object": list, "has_more": 0, "data": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 
0x600002c46800>(
{
"billing_details" =     {
    address =         {
        city = "<null>";
        country = "<null>";
        line1 = "<null>";
        line2 = "<null>";
        "postal_code" = 4553;
        state = "<null>";
    };
    email = "<null>";
    name = "<null>";
    phone = "<null>";
};
card =     {
    brand = mastercard;
    checks =         {
        "address_line1_check" = "<null>";
        "address_postal_code_check" = pass;
        "cvc_check" = pass;
    };
    country = US;
    "exp_month" = 2;
    "exp_year" = 2021;
    fingerprint = OqzEjapFroTZ3Lqn;
    funding = credit;
    "generated_from" = "<null>";
    last4 = 4444;
    "three_d_secure_usage" =         {
        supported = 1;
    };
    wallet = "<null>";
};
created = 1588901399;
customer = "cus_HDdTb2Me8W6MUM";
  id = "pm_1GgL2JB7pjuLNBFRl48k0nyg";
  livemode = 0;
  metadata =     {
  };
  object = "payment_method";
  type = card;
}
)
]
```

**Submit Data To Url:**

```
do {
      guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {return};

      let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)

      var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 540)

      urlRequest.httpMethod = method;
      urlRequest.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")  // the request is JSON
      urlRequest.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")        // the expected response is also JSON

      let httpBodyData : Data?

    try httpBodyData = JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: [.fragmentsAllowed]);

      urlRequest.httpBody = httpBodyData;

      let dataTask = defaultSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (responseData, urlResponse, error) in

          if error == nil {
              do {
                let response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData!, options: [.fragmentsAllowed]) as! [String : Any];
                  completion(response, nil);
              }
              catch {
                  print("Exception")
                  let response : [String : Any] = [String : Any]()
                  completion(response, error);
              }
          }
          else {
              let response : [String : Any] = [String : Any]()
              completion(response, error);
          }
      });

      dataTask.resume();
  }
  catch {
      print("Excetion in submitDataToURL")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fetched the `Id` using the code below.

```
let response = jsonResponse

let results = response["data"] as? [[String: Any]]

let firstDict = results?.first

guard let id = firstDict?["id"] as? String else { return }
```

Answer (score 0):

`paymentMethods.list` returns an object with a `data` property that contains an array of PaymentMethods. In your code you'd access this with something like:

`jsonResponse["data"][0]["id]`

Assuming you're correctly serializing the JSON object in your `submitDataToURL` function.

Comment: I get `Value of type 'Any?' has no subscripts`. I have updated my question with my `submitDataToUrl` function if you think that might be causing the issue.